# Reset all sessions in Spring Boot app (JSESSIONID)?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-boot-actuator

I'm troubleshooting authentication/registration flow and need a quick way to reset all sessions server side (no `curl` or other client side logout magic!).

Is there Spring Actuator or JMX ready endpoint to invalidate all sessions?

We use Tomcat as am embedded server, if it helps...

Comment: (1) Tomcat StandardManager MBean can be used to invoke `getActiveSessions` and then `expireSession` on each session. or (2) Spring Security's 'SessionRegistry' can be used to get all principals' sessions and then invoke `removeSessionInformation` on each session.

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is a dedicated Spring Actuator Endpoint:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#production-ready-endpoints

> `sessions` - Allows retrieval and deletion of user sessions from a Spring Session-backed session store. Requires a Servlet-based web application using Spring Session.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/actuator-api/html/#sessions-retrieving

> 21.2. Retrieving a Single Session

```
curl 'http://localhost:8080/actuator/sessions/4db5efcc-99cb-4d05' -i -X GET
curl 'http://localhost:8080/actuator/sessions/4db5efcc-99cb-4d05' -i -X DELETE
```

Extra step to enable Actuator endpoints:

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include:
  - env
  - health
  - info
  - sessions
```